# Areasinus hyperbolicus

Tags: functions, trigonometry, language-design

Why is there a function `ArcSinh[]`?
Shouldn't this be called `ArSinh`, since it is connected with an *area* and not with the *length* (arc)?

Comment: Huh, I had no idea this was a controversy.  ArcSinh turns up ~70K results on Google while ArSinh gets only ~50K, so at least by popularity ArcSinh wins.  Seems pretty Arcane to me though!

Comment: @ChrisK: There is more behind, check out the geometric interpretation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function

Comment: Since *Mathematica* follows usual (at least usual in the English-speaking world) mathematical terminology in this respect surely this is more of a question of mathematical terminology than one of *Mathematica*-l terminology.  And therefore off-topic hereabouts.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: This is not a question of taste since there is a difference between "arc" and "area".

Comment: I don't suggest that this is a question of taste, only that you (or rather the question) are tilting at the windmill of English-language mathematics not the rather smaller windmill of *Mathematica*.

Comment: The bigger problem is that this is not really a practical question. It is a discussion starter or a complaint, depending on how you view it. Either way, it is not appropriate for a QA site.  It's something you might discuss in the chatroom, or maybe on Wolfram Community. Or if you feel really strongly about it, you might even contact Wolfram Support, but I do not think that would be a very productive exchange.

Comment: see here if you would like to engage in this pointless debate: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Inverse_hyperbolic_functions

Comment: This is probably an issue only because in the English speaking world somebody had the misguided idea that `arc` is an appropriate prefixe for the inverse of any function that sounds like it might a trig function. [English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions), [German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Areafunktion) and [Russian](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) editions of Wikipedia all

Comment: (cont'd) use `ar` instead of `arc`. Apparently so does [ISO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_80000-2) as suggested by the English WP. So, Wolfram is the odd one out.